# Where a const reference refers to?

Tags: c++, const-reference

There is a simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int counter = 3;

const int& f() {
    return counter++;
}

const int& g() {
    return counter++;
}

const int& h(int w) {
    counter = w;
    return counter;
}

void main()
{
    const int& x = f();
    const int& y = g();
    const int& z = g();
    const int& t = h(123);
    counter = 45678;
    printf("%d %d %d %d", x, y, z, t);
}
```

Why its output is `5 5 5 45678`? Especially, why x and y are 5? If they are still connected to the counter after initialization, why they are not 45679 or something like?

Comment: UB. Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: You are hitting undefined behavior as you are returning a reference to a temp value

Comment: Enabling some warnings (`g++ -Wall`) reveals "warning: returning reference to temporary" in `f` and `g`. (My compiler also says "error: '::main' must return 'int'".)

Comment: What do _you_ think they refer to?

Comment: @DanielA.White Where? `counter` is a variable in file scope, not in local function scope. Never mind: `counter++` returns a reference to a temporary.

Comment: `counter++` is a temporary object. `return ++counter;` would be safe, as would `counter++; return counter;` and `return counter += 1;`

Comment: If you try `return ++counter;` instead you should get a different result. And it wouldn't be UB.

Answer (score 5):

Because of post-incrementation that `f` and `g` do.

```cpp
const int& f() {
    return counter++;
}

const int& g() {
    return counter++;
}
```

`counter++` doesn't actually return the `counter`, but a temporary `int` object returned by `operator++(int)`.
In C++, `opreator++` has two forms.

```cpp
Type& operator++(); //pre-increment
Type operator++(int); //post-increment
```

The `int` argument in the 2nd version is a dummy used to distinguish the calls, as you can't overload on return type alone
As you can see the post-increment returns by value, not reference, so you're returning a reference to a temporary variable!

You can see warning from GCC and Clang if you turn them on.
https://godbolt.org/z/f1fMP463a

So overall you invoke UB as the references you return are dangling. You ran into the worst case where it just seems to work.

Also, `main` must return `int` in C++.

Comment: To be fully precise: `main` returning `int` is only required for *hosted* environment (i.e. running an operating system), which *usually* is case, but not always...

Answer (score 3):

Your program has undefined behaviour. The return values of `f` and `g` cease to exist at the end of the statements that call them, so `x`, `y` and `z` don't refer to anything after their declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to the answers given so far: *Why* undefined behaviour?
Let's consider a *hypothetical* implementation of operator++:

```
template <typename T>
T& operator++(T& t) // pre-increment:
{
    t = t + 1;
    return t;
}
// should be clear so far...

template <typename T>
T operator++(T& t, int) // post-increment:
{
    // t = t + 1; // cannot do now, how to return the old value then???
    T b = t;      // need to store the value in a backup copy first!
    t = t + 1;    // NOW we can
    return t;     // need to return the OLD value -> cannot return by reference either,
                  // it's a TEMPORARY ...
}
```

As you now use `operator++`, which itself returns a temporary, you return a reference to temporary that doesn't exist any more after after returning – *undefined behaviour*.

Why do you now see 5? Pure technically (still UB!): As `f` and `g` look identical they both use identical offsets to the stack's end on being called and as being called immediately one after another they both start at the same stack end – so they will store the temporary at the same stack address, which is where the reference gets bound to. Note that this finally contains the value *before* last increment, thus 5, not 6. `h` does not need any additional values on the stack, thus the value there won't get overwritten – just alike when doing the assignment, so the value is yet retained. You might have seen something totally different if for some reason `h` *did* use the stack itself...